# Split an array of strings into 2, use one as key and the other as value php

Tags: php, arrays

I have athe following array of strings: 
(var_dump result)

```
    array(17) {
  [15]=>
  string(14) "07-04-16 10:00"
  [16]=>
  string(14) "07-04-16 10:30"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "07-04-16 8:00"
  [0]=>
  string(14) "08-04-16 13:00"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "08-04-16 13:30"
  [7]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 16:00"
  [8]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 16:30"
  [9]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 17:00"
  [10]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 17:30"
  [11]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 18:00"
  [12]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 18:30"
  [13]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 19:00"
  [14]=>
  string(14) "12-04-16 19:30"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "13-04-16 11:30"
  [3]=>
  string(14) "13-04-16 12:00"
  [4]=>
  string(14) "13-04-16 12:30"
  [5]=>
  string(14) "13-04-16 13:00"
}
```

Is there a way to split the values on the " ", use the left portion as key and the right portion as value? I'm trying to do this without overwriting values so I would have something like:

```
"07-04-16" => "10:00","10:30"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop, explode and append the times to the date index:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    list($date, $time) = explode(' ', $value);
    $result[$date][] = $time;
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver, this is exactly what I needed, Thank you so much man!